# List of acronyms as an input of a separate file .tex and not in the main

Tags: glossaries, input

I'm trying to have a list of acronyms in my paper, but since it will be really long I don't want to write all the `\newglossaryentry` in the main. I tried to create a separate .tex file and use `\input{}` but it doesn't print anything when compiled.

Here's the main:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}          
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{url}                    
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}             
\usepackage{array}                  
\usepackage{gensymb}                
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
....


\input{acro}
\printglossaries

....

\end{document}
```

Where the acro.tex is for example:

```
 
\newglossaryentry{CDR}
{
    name={\textbf{CDR}},
    description={Critical Design Review}
}
 
\newglossaryentry{FVT}
{
    name={\textbf{FVT}},
    description={Functional Validation Test-bench}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use the defined symbols or add them to the glossaries. Now, you only defined them how they should look like, but not added them to actually be printed. ```\glssaddall``` adds all defined acronyms to the list of acronyms.

Comment: Do I insert it right before `\printglossaries` ? Because it gives me an error

Comment: @Gin, if you look into the Guide for beginners and also the user guide on CTAN, the command isn't mentioned there, while `\glsaddall` is ... just a typo  ... I suggest spending some time on reading ... https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries

Comment: @Gin, if your acronym-list will have a few hundred or so entries and still want to have an overview, select etc., may be you should consider a different route than writing them all manually into a file ...

Comment: @MS-SPO Okay thank you! I will look into it

Comment: Does `\glsaddall` resovle your problem? If not, have you run `makeglossaries`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it: just work through the ["Getting Started" section of the Guide for beginners](https://mirror.funkfreundelandshut.de/latex/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf).

With your acro.tex, change your main file to, and use your entries like this `\gls{yourEntry}`, which will list the ones you used - and you don't want to put the worlds knowledge into your glossary, do you?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries%       <<<
\input{acro}%               <<<

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 Let's use only one entry: \gls{CDR}.%      <<<

 \printnoidxglossaries%     <<<
\end{document}
```

[image: result]